# File 'lipsum.sty' not found

Tags: miktex

I downloaded a LaTeX template to start writing my report, and as a first-timer in LaTeX, I get the error message

> LaTeX error: File `lipsum.sty` not found

along with two other messages (Emergency stop + Fatal error occurred). I am using TeXnicCenter on Windows 7. My distribution is MiKTeX 2.9.

Comment: Welcome  to TeX SX! Which distribution do you have?

Comment: I am using MikTex 2.9

Comment: I suppose you made a basic install. Launch `MiKTeX Package Manager`, as administrator. Once launched it will, after some time, show you the list of all available packages, marked as installed or not, at which date, &c. Right click on  the `lipsum` package, and select `install`.

Comment: I Just did as you mentioned , this is what i get, a box message untitled MIkTex Problem Report : NO DATA get proxy host by name failed in tcp_connect()

Comment: Could you explain? I never had  such a message.

Comment: Did  you  go to the `Repository` menu to select a repository from internet?

Comment: I Launched MikTEX Package Manager, then when i click on lipsum >install , i get a message box named "MIkTex Problem Report" , Data :  get proxy host by name failed in tcp_connect()

Comment: Maybe select a repository first.

Comment: No i did not select any repository from internet (just to be specific, i can compile and execute other tex files, but the one where i'm using \usepackage{lipsum} is not working

Comment: Of course! if you have a basic install, this one is not installed by default

Comment: I tried to install from a repository from internet, i get the same message boc indicating some proxy problem

Comment: It may be a problem with your connection.

Comment: I just unchecked the  "using proxy" option, and re installed lipsum as you've requested, it seems to be downloading

Comment: It seems to be working but I still  have a problem with the following packages  \usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}, \usepackage[french]{minitoc}, \usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,epsfig,epstopdf,titling,url,array}, \usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}, do i have to do the same as i did for lipsum?

Comment: @NewUser Yes...

Comment: It's Working ! Sir thank you very much, you just made my day ;)

Comment: Don't use `epsfig`: it's outdated and replaced with `graphicx`. The `ams…` series is installed by default.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by comments.